# Convert OWL Ontology to OBO

Tags: perl, xml-parsing, owl, ontology

I need to convert a OWL ontology to OBO.

I've tried this tool https://github.com/ontodev/robot/ but the output format isn't correct at all, just some parts.

Also OBO-EDIT2 and Protegé but the weren't able to do a conversion.

Lastly I've tried this Perl module http://search.cpan.org/~easr/ however it gives this error

Undefined subroutine &XML::Parser called at /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/OBO/Parser/OWLParser.pm line 146.

And trying to install XML::Parser always ends with an error.

Could anyone help me to convert the Ontology?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried https://github.com/owlcollab/owltools/?

> And trying to install XML::Parser always ends with an error.

What commands are you running to install XML::Parser? What is that error? Can you install other perl modules ok with the same commands? What about ones which require make?

Comment: Hello. In the owltools page says this "The use of owltools will be phased out for this purpose in favor of ROBOT". Robot is one of the tools I tried.

Comment: The problem with XML::Parser was that I didn't have expat installed. Now I was able to install it, however when I try to do the conversion the error persists.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using OWL API, OBO is one of the supported output formats. It is sufficient to pass an OBODocumentFormat to the saveOntology() method.